# Can I completely rely in bash shell installed in windows and the one in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been asked to write a manual on installing, running and editing a program in which all has to be done in bash. The problem is that I only have access to Linux terminal (can't really afford a windows license), but most of the people that will read my notes will run it on a bash terminal installed in a Windows environment.

So my question is: how similar are both environments? My concerns is whether or not I can rely on `make`, `grep`, flex library and if I can still define variables using `.bashrc` or similar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My concerns is whether I can rely on make, grep, ... flex library?

The Windows Linux Subsystem (which includes `bash`) is still experimental (under development) and contains many bugs.

You can find the list at [Microsoft/BashOnWindows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues), and there are currently 565 open issues.

Without knowing exactly what you are planning to do I can only advise you to check this list very carefully.

Your employer should buy you a Windows license if you decide to go ahead otherwise you won't be able to test your `bash` scripts on Windows.

---

#### Is that the only alternative for running bash in windows?

There are other bash ports which will run on Windows. You need to check if they include the other components you need.

The list includes:

- [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) - probably the most comprehensive
- [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/)
- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

and probably others...

Comment: Is that the only alternative for running bash in windows? I was working under the possibility that there were more than one "bash install" for Linux. And it is not my employer, it's an autonomous group thing (if it were my employer I'd say the same thing about the license).

Comment: @TomCho Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However I came across some new information that better suits my question and may interest you. Please take a look at the answer I posted. CHeers

Comment: @TomCho You have completely misunderstood. The feature you refer to in your answer **is** "The Windows Linux Subsystem (which includes bash) is still experimental (under development) and contains many bugs."

Answer (score -1):

Just including this since it's kind of new information, but as of August 2016 (the [Windows 10's anniversary update](http://www.howtogeek.com/248177/whats-new-in-windows-10s-anniversary-update/)) you can run an Ubuntu 14.04 terminal in Windows 10 natively, without the needed of any emulators.

The instructions to do it are [pretty straightforward](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3106463/windows/how-to-get-bash-on-windows-10-with-the-anniversary-update.html) and it works for any up-to-date Windows 10 64bit computer. Since you'll be *actually running Ubuntu* then no portability problems are expected.

Comment: The problem is that the OP hasn't got Windows.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood. The feature you refer to in your answer **is** "The Windows Linux Subsystem (which includes bash) is still experimental (under development) and contains many bugs."